# How to render video in H.265 HEVC?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video, file-format

I am able to edit H.265 movies in VSE by adding them like any other movie.
Does anyone know how to render a resulting project in H.265 using Blender?  I've tested v2.72b on Ubuntu 15, as well as the latest and greatest on Windows 7.

When looking at the Properties window in VSE, under the output section, a number of file formats are listed, including H.264, but no H.265.  Same in the Encoding section of Properties.  H.264 but no H.265.  Is that something I can add to current versions of Blender?

Comment: Seems not possible at the moment. I'd suggest rendering an image sequence and *encode it via ffmpeg* afterwards: http://superuser.com/questions/785528/how-to-generate-an-mp4-with-h-265-codec-using-ffmpeg

Comment: For not having to temporarily save out an image sequence you might use the Frame Server feature and use a recent version of ffmpeg for the encoding. There have been plans to update the included ffmpeg version though...

Comment: Use external ffmpeg binary on the exported image sequence or directly from a script like [here](https://github.com/ichlubna/blenderScripts/blob/master/MISC/ffExport.py)

Answer (score 3):

For future reference.
Blender does support the H.265 HEVC equivalent made by google, WEBM/VP9

From VP9 Wikipedia:

> VP9 is an open and royalty-free video coding format developed by
> Google.
>
> VP9 is the successor to VP8 and competes mainly with MPEG's High
> Efficiency Video Coding (HEVC/H.265). At first, VP9 was mainly used on
> Google's video platform YouTube.The emergence of the Alliance
> for Open Media, and its support for the ongoing development of the
> successor AV1, of which Google is a part, led to growing interest in
> the format.

**Example for VP9 output**

File Format: FFmpeg video

Encoding container: MPEG-4

Video Codec: WEBM/VP9

Edited For clarification: While WEBM/VP9 is not exactly H265 HEVC, it is the performance equivalent and already on Blender.